# Java Generics & Collections, why can't I instantiate new List with wildcards?

Tags: java, generics, collections

Why can I have a method receiving a list with wildcards:

```
public processGenerics(List<? extends User> users){...}
```

but I cannot instantiate that same List in a similar way?

```
List<? extends User> alist = new ArrayList<? extends User>();
```

[Edited, not part of the original question, but relevant] Why can't I do casting with Collections the same way of normal inheritance:

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<Admin>();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most confusing aspect of your problem is the underlying mental switch you must undergo with generic types vs. classic raw types.

Before Generics, each variable had a definite type, such as Object. Although you could assign a String into it, a String still **is an** Object, so the paradigm holds—in all cases you are assigning something that **is an Object** into an Object var.

Not so with Generics. You may have a `List<? extends Number>`, which can be assigned from a range of types that have no `instanceof` relation to the declared variable type, but only satisfy a certain **pattern**. The pattern is described by the wildcard.

So, to make your life easier when you reason about generic variable types, you need to abandon the simple and cozy notion of a definite type and think in terms of these "type patterns".

As far as the second part of your question: `List<User>` and `List<Admin>` are completely unrelated types, regardless of the fact that `User` and `Admin` are related. That's how Generics work, and there's a good reason for it. Java cannot allow you to add `OrdinaryUser` to a `List<Admin>`, and under your assumption that could happen:

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<Admin>();
users.add(new OrdinaryUser()); // shouldn't be allowed!
```

The official term is that generic types are *invariant* with respect to their type parameter. It is best to google around for this term as it is already very well covered.

Comment: I like your description. Though, why doesn't this work? List<User> users = new ArrayList<Admin>();

Comment: That's the trick: `List<User>` and `List<Admin>` are **completely unrelated types**, regardless of the fact that `User` and `Admin` are related. That's how Generics work, and there's a good reason for it. Java cannot allow you to add `OrdinaryUser` to a `List<Admin>`, and under your assumption, that could happen.

Comment: @Pomario The short answer is "because the latter is not a subtype of the former". The long answer can probably be found on SO in various forms many, many times, and can definitely be found in Angelika Langer's FAQ: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ102

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes - I must have skimmed your answer and interpreted "type" to be the generic type parameter, rather than the type of the parameterized class. I've undone the -1 and as consolation given you a +1. No hard feelings I hope.

Answer (score 4):

The construct:

```
List<? extends User> user
```

means a variable that can hold an instance of `List<T>`, where `T` is some **unknown** subtype of user. When you're actually instantiating an `ArrayList<T>` is the one time where you always know what type it's supposed to hold, so it's not useful to let you express this uncertainty there.

To put this in a different way: a variable can hold objects of (potentially) many different types. An object instance is only of its own one type. That's why variable declarations have to be more flexible.

Answer (score 3):

You can't instantiate a wildcarded instance. You can only instantiate a specific instance, eg:

```
List<? extends User> alist1 = new ArrayList<User>();
List<? extends User> alist2 = new ArrayList<SubClassOfUser>();
```

What `List<? extends User>` means is "A List whose type is unknown at compile time, but which has the upper bound of `User` - that is either `User` or a subclass of `User`"

While a *variable*  may be defined with a wildcard, an instance may not - it's got to be a List of *something*

Comment: You just repeated the question.

Answer (score -1):

The new operator instantiates a class by allocating memory for a new object and returning a reference to that memory. [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

You can't know how much memory to allocate when you use a wild card for object creation.

What you pass as parameter type to a method involves no memory allocation.

Comment: -1: This is patently false. An object reference in Java always uses the same amount of memory, which means any instantiation of a generic type will have the same memory layout.

Comment: What exactly are you claiming is "patently" false ? I just quoted the Oracle tutorial. The new creates the object not the reference.

Comment: Ah type erasure - all instances of generic types have the same run-time representation.

Comment: This doesn't even have anything to do with type erasure, that's just a design choice of generics. At the memory layout level, you can think of the JVM as only recognizing the builtin set of primitive "value" types (`char`, `int` etc.), and a single "reference" type `Object`. (To make an analogy to C#.) To store any object reference in an object requires, say, 4 bytes of memory, no matter what type. It's not that all instances of a generic type have the same representation, it's that all object references - which is what's stored in an object - do. This is how things worked since ever in Java.

Comment: Why're you so fixated on the references ? The objects themselves have to be created on heap. And not all objects can be assigned the same amount of memory - that would be ridiculous.

Comment: You still don't seem to understand. In Java, objects do not really contain other objects. They only contain references to other objects. E.g. let's say that an `ArrayList` only has one field of type `Object[]`. (Arrays are also object references.) This means that when `new ArrayList()` allocates memory, you only need to allocate for example 4 bytes of memory. (4 bytes overhead, 4 bytes to store the field.) Obviously the array will then take more memory, but that's not allocated when you do `new ArrayList()` - it's allocated when the `ArrayList` constructor does `new Object[]`.

Comment: So, type erasure or not, because an object reference always takes up the same amount of memory, allocating memory for an instance of our imaginary `ArrayList` class will only ever need 8 bytes. Nothing about the introduction of generics as Java implements them changed this, which is why bringing up type erasure doesn't make sense in this context. My point is that to allocate memory for a new, *empty* object instance, you don't really need to know up front how much memory you need for whatever gets instantiated in its constructor - which is why the exact types of the object fields don't matter.

Comment: Thanks for your replies @millimoose. Need to look into this a lot more when i've some time - [this](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ609) suggests that there's even a way to create an object with wild card parameterised type.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that trick. Interesting, if ultimately pointless. (This time indeed because of type erasure. As far as Java is concerned, there really is no difference between instantiating a wildcard-parameterised type, and instantiating a parameterised type the "normal" way then immediately assigning it to a wildcard-parameterised variable.)